# Access violation reading location 0xfdfdfdfd. IN C

Tags: c

I would like to get your help. I was debugging my code and i found out the compiler kicks  me out in this line

```
 if(strcmp(text1[i],text1[i+1]) > 0 )
```

the error msg i get is

```
Unhandled exception at 0x542ed442 (msvcr100d.dll) in LB11_12.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xfdfdfdfd.
```

and it's asks me if i want to break or continue
why does its happen?

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#define LINES 4
#define length 100

void SortText1(char **text1);
void SortText2(char **text2);
void PrintStr1(char **text1);
void PrintStr2(char **text2);
void main ()
{
    int i;
    char **text1;
    char **text2;
    char **text3;
    text1=(char **)malloc(LINES*sizeof(char *));
        if(!text1) // Terms - if there is not enough memory,print error msg and exit the program.
            {
                printf("alloc failed\n");
                return ;
            }
     for (i=0 ; i<LINES; i++)
     {
        text1[i] =(char*) malloc(length*sizeof(char));
     }

    text2=(char **)malloc(LINES*sizeof(char *));
        if(!text2) // Terms - if there is not enough memory,print error msg and exit the program.
            {
                printf("alloc failed\n");
                return ;
            }
     for (i=0 ; i<LINES; i++)
         {
        text2[i] =(char*) malloc(length*sizeof(char));
         }
     text3=(char **)malloc((LINES+LINES)*sizeof(char *));
        if(!text3) // Terms - if there is not enough memory,print error msg and exit the program.
            {
                printf("alloc failed\n");
                return ;
            }
     for (i=0 ; i<LINES+LINES; i++)
     {
        text3[i] =(char*) malloc(length*sizeof(char));
     }

    printf("First string,Please enter %d names (only capital letters,without spaces):", LINES);
     for ( i=0 ; i<LINES ; i++)
         {
          gets(text1[i]);
         }
    printf("Second string,Please enter %d names (only capital letters,without spaces):", LINES);
    for ( i=0 ; i<LINES ; i++)
      {
          gets(text2[i]);
      }
    PrintStr1(text1);
    PrintStr2(text2);
    SortText1(text1);
    system("pause");
    return ;
}
void SortText1(char **text1)
{

    int i,j,k;
    for (i=LINES-1 ; i>0 ; i--)
    {
        for ( j=0 ; j<i ; j++ )
        {
            if(strcmp(text1[i],text1[i+1]) > 0 )
            {
                char *temp=text1[i+1];
                text1[i+1]=text1[i];
                text1[i]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("The first string sorted:\n");
    for ( k=0 ; k<LINES ; k++)
        {
            printf("%s ",text1[k]);
        }
    printf("\n");
}
void PrintStr1(char **text1)
{
    int i;
    printf("The first string of NAMES:\n");
    for ( i=0 ; i<LINES ; i++)
        {
            printf("%s ",text1[i]);
        }
    printf("\n");
}
void PrintStr2(char **text2)
{
    int i;
    printf("The second string of NAMES:\n");
    for ( i=0 ; i<LINES ; i++)
        {
            printf("%s ",text2[i]);
        }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: You should not use `gets` use `fgets` instead. Have you tried to use a debugger to investigate the problem further?

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> for (i=LINES-1 ; i>0 ; i--)
> ...
>     if(strcmp(text1[i],text1[i+1]) > 0 )
> ```

On the first iteration you'll access `text1[LINES-1]` and `text1[LINES]`. But `text1[LINES]` is out of bounds, therefore illegal to access - doubly illegal, since you didn't allocate any memory to it either.

---

Side note: it is interesting the way the magic `0xfdfdfdfd` lies just outside the accessible space, specifically targeting off-by-one errors.

Comment: How do I set it to be in the system memory allocation. Why not have access? I set him start the program memory space

Comment: @SagiBinder WHat are you trying to achieve ?